# How do I use Time Machine to restore my Mac to its previous state?

Tags: macos, mac, backup, osx-lion, time-machine

OSX Lion

I accidentally installed a bad driver, and it's causing problems. I want to use Time Machine to have my ***entire*** system go back to its previous state.

So I went into "Recovery HD" option (ALT + power on). Then, I selected the "Restore from Time Machine" option.

It ran for 3 hours....but after it finished, **it did not restore the system to my previous state**.  Maybe my files were restored....but my system was not.

How can I restore my FULL system to my previous state?

I have also tried "Reinstall OSX Lion" option...but that did not fix it either...the system remained the same.

Note: The bad driver was Nvidia CUDA.  Even if I do a fresh wipe of the entire system, will this driver be gone forever? Or does it stick to the hardware?

Comment: Do you have access to Disk Utility from Recovery HD? If so, you can try to delete the system partition and restore the system from backup with no way of restoring the files that were previously there. Double-check your backups to be sure they're good before doing that.

Comment: @DanielBeck my system is installed on "Macintosh HD". Should I go into Disk Utility and "erase" this?

Comment: You would have to do it from booting the DVD. But then under Disk Utility, he's basically saying to format the system partition

Comment: Exactly. If you delete it first, there's no way some clever logic will keep the files you don't want around.